# How do I return string array and string to the array of multispell?

Tags: java, arrays, string, methods, return

Using the main below, create the methods that will give the `String[]` result.
Please write the loop in the main to print the array of a multi spell.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
// Create array here

// use your array to create new array here 
String[] multispell = Attack(“your array”, “ball”);
```

**Output:**

```
Cast Fire ball!!!
Cast Ice ball!!!
Cast Earth ball!!!
Cast Lightning ball!!!
Cast Wind ball!!
```

**my program:**

```
public class Paper {
    public static void main (String args[]) {

        String[] kind = new String[5];

        String [] multispell = Attack4 ( kind , "ball" );

        for (int i = 0 ; i< multispell.length ; i++) {

            System.out.println ("Cast " + multispell[i]+ "!!!");

    }   
    }

    public static String[] Attack4() {
        String [] kind111 = {"Fire", "Ice", "Earth", "Lightning", "Wind"};
        return kind111 ;

    }
}
```

Comment: which programming language are you using, please add as a tag

Comment: java programming language

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking

Comment: The first part is the question of my assignment with the output. Could you please help me with the question to get the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] kind = new String[] {
        "Fire", "Ice", "Earth", "Lightning", "Wind"
    };

    String[] multispell = Attack(kind, "ball");
    for (int i = 0; i < multispell.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Cast " + multispell[i] + "!!!");
    }

}

public static String[] Attack(String[] orig, String attach) {
    String[] result = new String[orig.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < orig.length; i++) {
        result[i] = orig[i] + " " + attach;
    }
    return result;
}
```